# How do I install an R package from the source tarball on windows?

Tags: r, shell

The [forecast package](http://robjhyndman.com/software/forecast/) for **R** has been updated to version **2.12**, but there are currently only windows binarys for 2.11 available on CRAN.

How do I install an R package from [the source](http://cran.ms.unimelb.edu.au/src/contrib/forecast_2.12.tar.gz) on Windows?

Comment: The binary simply hasn't been picked up by your mirror yet.  Get the [forecast_2.12 Windows binary](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/r-release/forecast_2.12.zip) from the main CRAN repository, or wait a day for the mirror to update.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I know this is an old question but it came up first in my Google search for this same question, even though I knew the answer I just wanted something to copy and paste.  Which makes it worth improving the answer for future reference.  So here is what works for me:

Install [rtools](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/), then:

```
install.packages(path_to_file, repos = NULL, type="source")
```

Comment: Thank you for coming back to the question!

Comment: You just need Rtools; devtools is unnecessary. `install.packages` is from `utils`, which is distributed with R.

Comment: Yes, of course you're right @JoshuaUlrich, and I've amended accordingly.

Answer (score 9):

Start by reviewing the [section on Windows packages](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Windows-packages) in the [R Installation and Administration](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html) manual, then carefully follow the instructions from [The Windows toolset](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#The-Windows-toolset) appendix.

I know it's usually bad form to mainly provide links in an answer, but these are links to the canonical references on this topic. I simply link to them rather than summarize their contents, since they should be accurate for the most current R release.

Comment: So the answer appears to be "very carefully."  Thanks for the information!

Comment: More accurately. Read the Manual. Don't guess.

Comment: You can't break anything, so just go ahead.

Answer (score 8):

Two answers that may help you avoid the hassle of installing Rtools.

1. Use http://win-builder.r-project.org/ to build a binary version, download it, and install (using `install.packages(...,repos=NULL)`)
2. *If* the package has no binary component (i.e. no `src` directory with C, C++, or Fortran code that needs to be compiled during installation (not true for `forecast`, but possibly useful some other time) then simply specifying `type="source"` within the `install.packages` call (whether from a repository or a local copy of the source tarball (`.tar.gz` file)) will install the source package, even on Windows.

Answer (score 5):

1. Download the package *.tar.gz.
2. make sure you have Rtools installed.
3. Make sure the R and Rtools paths are added in the environment varialble.
4. Open a command prompt. Type R CMD INSTALL packagename.tar.gz.

it will work i hope.

Comment: I am not quite sure i get number 3. How would I add the Rtools path in the environment variable? install.packages(....,environment=(rtools=<path>))?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but I found the following method to work (based in part on the answers above):

1) Download the package .tar

2) Move the package to the directory with your user R libraries (e.g., in my case it was "C:/Users/yourUserName/Documents/R/win-library/3.3")

3) Within Rstudio (or elsewhere, probably), run the command... `install.packages("packageName.tar", repos=NULL, type="source")`

That worked for me at least. Hope it's helpful!

Answer (score 3):

To install a package from a `.tar.gz` file, follow these steps:

- Launch `R` to have the R command prompt
- Type: `install.packages(<path_to_tar.gz_file>, repos = NULL)`

or launch directly:

```
R CMD INSTALL <path_to_.tar.gz_file>
```

> You need to have **R** installed but you don't need **RTools**