# Install rJava in R

Tags: rjava

I have R and Java installed on C:\Program Files. I am receiving this message when i try to load the rJava library. I have successfully installed the rJava package.  thanks.

> library(rJava)
>   Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
>     call: fun(libname, pkgname)
>     error: No CurrentVersion entry in Software/JavaSoft registry! Try re-installing Java and make sure R and Java have matching architectures.
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’

Comment: I ran into a lot of install issues with rJava. It would install but not load correctly until I tried installing it as root, from source. All the different things I tried are documented in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26948777/how-can-i-make-rjava-use-the-newer-version-of-java-on-osx/32544358#32544358). I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Is your Java_HOME path variable the same for both installations. 
Try echo $JAVA_HOME and see what happens?
Also the installation suggests that you need to install the JDK not just the java library. 
Here is a link the most recent JDK:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html