# Where does rJava takes location of JDK from?

Tags: r, rjava

Where does rJava take location of JDK from ? I have `JAVA_HOME` set but on `install.packages("rJava")` I get this

```
checking Java support in R... present:
interpreter : '/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/bin/java'
archiver    : '/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/jar'
compiler    : '/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/javac'
header prep.: '/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/javah'
cpp flags   : '-I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux'
java libs   : '-L/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm'
checking whether Java run-time works... 
./configure: line 3736: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/bin/java: No such file or directory
no
configure: error: Java interpreter '/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/bin/java' does not work
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rJava’
```

I can't figure out where it takes `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/` from.

Comment: Try to run `sudo R CMD javareconf` http://stackoverflow.com/a/34367319/1370303

Answer (score 2):

From R which stores this when it is configured:

```
edd@max:~$ grep ^JAVA /etc/R/Makeconf 
JAVA = /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/bin/java
JAVAC = /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/javac
JAVAH = /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/javah
JAVA_HOME = /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
JAVA_CPPFLAGS = -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/linux
JAVA_LIBS = -L$(JAVA_HOME)/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm
JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH = $(JAVA_HOME)/jre/lib/amd64/server
edd@max:~$
```

If you update your Java toolchain you can update this via `R CMD javareconf`.

Comment: Any advice for how to see these specs if you don't have a `/etc/R/` directory?

Comment: Of course. Replace `/etc/` with `R.home(component="etc")` --- or in other words, look at `file.path(R.home(component="etc"), "Makeconf")`.