# Error: BigR[bigr.connect]: Required library 'BigRResultSet' could not be found

Tags: r, biginsights, bigr

I'm trying to connect to bigr:

```
connected <- bigr.connect(
    host = hostname, 
    user = username,
    password = password,
    ssl = TRUE,
    trustStorePath = paste(projdir, "/truststore.jks", sep=""),
    trustStorePassword = "mypassword",
    keyManager = "SunX509"
    )
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error: BigR[bigr.connect]: Required library 'BigRResultSet' could not be found.
```

Note BigRResultSet.jar exists in the libpath:

```
$ ls -l lib/bigr/
total 1844
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant    6587 Jun 21 19:37 BigRResultSet.jar
```

Any idea what could be causing this issue?

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you ever find a fix for this? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find a fix.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer (at least for OSX 10.11.1), first run

```
sudo R CMD javareconf
```

on the commandline, make sure to note your JAVA_HOME, next download and install the newest version of rJava

```
wget http://www.rforge.net/rJava/snapshot/rJava_0.9-7.tar.gz
R CMD INSTALL rJava_0.9-7.tar.gz
```

do the same for bigr, then open RStudio and run the following

```
dyn.load('/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib')
require(rJava)
library(bigr)
conn <- bigr.connect(host="xxxx",user="xxxx", password="xxxx")
```

using your JAVA_HOME (the part up to ../jre). Answers were found [How can I make rJava use the newer version of java on osx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26948777/how-can-i-make-rjava-use-the-newer-version-of-java-on-osx) and http://charlotte-ngs.github.io/2016/01/MacOsXrJavaProblem.html.