# Loading R package xlsx: Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace()

Tags: r, package, xlsx

I tried to load the R package xlsx:

```
library('xlsx')
```

But I got the following error:

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'xlsx', details:
  call: .jinit()
  error: Cannot create Java virtual machine (-1)
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘xlsx’ was built under R version 3.2.3 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’
```

My R-session aborts when I try .jinit()

Any help is much appreciated.

**Edit:**

I updated R Studio to the newest version and executed

```
update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE)
```

but still got the following error:

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'xlsx', details:
  call: .jinit()
  error: Cannot create Java virtual machine (-1)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’
```

**Edit 2:**

This question is still unsolved. 
As Pascal in the comments below suggested I looked for the windows equivalent command of:

```
R CMD javareconf
```

After many hours of searching I still didn't found it.

Comment: Upgrade R, `R CMD javareconf` and `update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE)`

Comment: It would seem you have the wrong version of R. Suggest updating.

Comment: @Pascal: could you please elaborate on what you mean with 'R CMD javareconf '

Comment: I would say it is written in the documentation.

Comment: @Pascal: I have no idea to which documentation you refer. Please be more specific

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-admin.html#Java-support

Comment: @Pascal: Thanks for your reply. You do refer to the windows command prompt right? If I run 'R CMD javareconf', I get the error "'R' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file".

Comment: If you are on Windows, the command is different. Please search. Last comment.

Comment: @Pascal: I did a long but unfortunately unsuccesful search. I found comparisons between linux and windows commands like this:http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/unix_for_dos_users.html
But I never found the windows equivalent of 'R CMD javareconf'

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem on Macbook. If you've upgraded Java recently, it is likely that you need to reconfigure.

For me, it got solved with,

step#1 `sudo R CMD javareconf` (On Windows, `sudo` not required. If you face "command not found" issue on Windows, [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077689/r-cmd-on-windows-7-error-r-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-comm))

step#2 `install.packages("rJava",type='source')` (inside `R` prompt)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

In case you don't have PATH variable set up properly, try to override it by using

```
options(java.home="PATH TO jre")
```

This might fix some issues.