# Cant start spark in terminal

Tags: r, apache-spark

I took the following steps to get spark up and running in rstudio

1. Downloaded it at: http://spark.apache.org/
2. Stored the file in the following dir: "C:\Users\Marc\Apache"

Now I have a bin file containing a sparkR file called: spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6. However when I open up my terminal, move to the right dir  and try to run it using:

`.bin\sparkR`

I get the following error:

```
R is not recognized as an internal or external command ....
```

Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

Comment: You miss r-base package. Check https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-r-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 1):

¿Do you have R installed and added to the PATH?

Also check [R CMD on Windows 7 Error - "R" is not recognized as an internal or external command,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077689/r-cmd-on-windows-7-error-r-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-comm) it may help you.