# Install error when install R package from github

Tags: r, github, installation, devtools

I try to install an R package `multidplyr` (which is currently not available from 
 CRAN) from github. I followed [this](http://blog.aicry.com/multidplyr-dplyr-meets-parallel-processing/) link.

I first `install.packages("devtools")`, then `library(devtools)`, then `devtools::install_github("hadley/multidplyr")`. But it generates the error message

```
Downloading GitHub repo hadley/multidplyr@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/hadley/multidplyr/zipball/master
Installing multidplyr
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --
no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
"C:/Users/FTXX/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpEpOeM9/devtools34805943869/hadley-multidplyr-0085ded"  \
  --library="C:/Users/FTXX/Documents/R/win-library/3.4" --install-tests 

Installation failed: Command failed (65535)
```

How to fix this problem? I found that if the package is on CRAN, then the system has no problem with `install.packages("abc")`, but as long as it needs to install packages from github, it has this problem. I also tried to install other packages from github, it also has the same problem.

I've followed [this](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/Install-Rtools-for-Windows) instructions to installed the `Rtools` (latest version). However, this problem of install packages from github still there. And I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33179156/installing-a-package-offline-from-github) instruction to first download the source zip package `multidplyr-master.zip` and unzip it into the local folder where all R packages stored and run

```
source <- devtools:::source_pkg("C:/Users/FTXX/Documents/R/win-
library/3.4/multidplyr-master")
install(source)
```

However, it reports similar error

```
Installing multidplyr
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --
no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/FTXX/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/multidplyr-master"  \
  --library="C:/Users/FTXX/Documents/R/win-library/3.4" --install-tests 

Error: Command failed (65535)
```

My R information is

```
 R.version
           _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          4.1                         
year           2017                        
month          06                          
day            30                          
svn rev        72865                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
nickname       Single Candle
```

Comment: Have you installed Rtools? You can't build on Windows without it. https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

Comment: That might be the reason. I just tried `install.packages("Rtools")`, it says `package ‘Rtools’ is not available (for R version 3.4.1)`. Should I move back to older version of R?

Comment: RTools is not a package and can't be installed as such. See the link by amatsuo_net.

Comment: @ftxx, Rtool is a windows executable, not a package.

Comment: @amatsuo_net Thanks! I've just followed [this](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/Install-Rtools-for-Windows) instruction and successfully installed the Rtools. However, it still does not solve the problem to install that package from github.... I also download that package and unzip it into the local folder where it stores all the r packages and run `source <- devtools:::source_pkg("C:/Users/FTXX/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/multidplyr-master");install(source)`. But it gives the same `Error: Command failed (65535)`

Comment: @Axeman thanks! I've just installed the Rtools. But it still does not solve the problem. I will update my post

Comment: You might have to install it in a path without any spaces, i.e. not in `Program Files`. (I've ran into that problem before, at least).

Comment: @Axeman I just uninstalled my R and Rstudio and reinstall them directly under C:\R and C:Rstudio (also I have C:\Rtools there). And I also did some search, I found that `find_rtools(T)` generates `Error: running command '"C:/R/R-34~1.1/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD config CC' had status 65535`. I think this is the key, my installed `rtools` is not recognized. But I didn't find good solution to that