# gpclib 'non zero-exit' error despite installing R tools, rgeos, maptools

Tags: r, shapefile, choropleth

This I know is a fairly common error with gpclib but I feel I've tried a lot of options and going around in circles. I come up against this issue when using 'fortify' to create a data frame from a UK local authority shapefile, so that eventually I can create a choropleth using ggplot2.

After trying to install gpclib package in the usual way I then tried to install from source:

```
install.packages("gpclib", type = "source")
```

Which says unsuccessfully unpacked but then 'ERROR: compilation failed for package 'gpclib'. I then read somewhere you need to have R Tools installed so I tried that but to no avail, same error. I then tried changing the order in which you attach rgeos and maptools because apparently this matters and this didn't work.

My code is dead simple and yet I'm at a brick wall early in the project.

Are there any other things to try to get gpclib installed?

Many thanks in anticipation, my code is below.
Henry

```
install.packages("rgdal")
library(rgdal)
install.packages("maptools")
library(maptools)
install.packages("rgeos")
library(rgeos)
myshape <- readShapeSpatial("infuse_ward_lyr_2011.shp")
myshape2 <- readShapeSpatial("infuse_dist_lyr_2011.shp")
plot(myshape)
plot(myshape2)
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)
str(myshape2)
myshape2frame <- fortify(myshape2, region="name")
install.packages("gpclib", type = "source")
library(gpclib)
gpclibPermit()
gpclibPermitStatus()
```

Comment: Not sure if this will help with your problem, but to install a package from source you also have to set `repos` to `NULL`. Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source

Comment: Thanks for your reply; unfortunately trying repos = NULL I get the following Warning: invalid package 'gpclib'
Error: ERROR: no packages specified

Comment: You have to give it the path to the downloaded package

Answer (score 1):

For anyone in future with this problem I solved this.

I knew I had to install R Tools but what I didn't know was that it's essential to have the location of R Tools in your Path.

I didn't want to  permanently set the path so I did so within R using:

```
pathRtools <- paste(c("c:\\Rtools\\bin",
"c:\\Rtools\\MinGW_64\\bin",
"c:\\MiKTeX\\miktex\\bin",
"c:\\R\\bin\\i386",
"c:\\windows",
"c:\\windows\\system32"), collapse=";")
Sys.setenv(PATH=paste(pathRtools,Sys.getenv("PATH"),sep=";"))
```

Please see the following post for details

[Install R package from source, without changing PATH (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042136/install-r-package-from-source-without-changing-path-windows)