# How to install .tar.gz source package in Windows XP 32-bit operational system

Tags: r

I failed in install source packages in Windows system. I have installed Rtools in order to install the source package based on the discussion available on the following link: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Installing-a-Package-tar-gz-in-windows-td3411393.html. By the way, only installing the Rtools is ok, isn't it? Do I need to run the Rtools?
(PS: adapt_1.0-4.tar.gz is placed in the R working directory)

```
> install.packages("adapt_1.0-4.tar.gz", type="source", repos=NULL) 
* installing *source* package 'adapt' ...
** Creating default NAMESPACE file
** libs
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'adapt'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.2/library/adapt'

warning：
1: running command'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.2/bin/i386/R CMD INSTALL -l "C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.2/library"   "adapt_1.0-4.tar.gz"'had 
status 1 

2: In install.packages("adapt_1.0-4.tar.gz", type = "source", repos = NULL) :
 installation of package ‘adapt_1.0-4.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the accepted answer of this question:

[How do I install an R package from the source tarball on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739837/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-the-source-tarball-on-windows)

If you have any *specific* problems you can ask a new question.