# Error: package ‘dmGWAS’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it

Tags: r, package

I downloaded the Windows binary file dmGWAS_2.3.zip [clickHere](http://bioinfo.mc.vanderbilt.edu/dmGWAS/dmGWAS_2.3.zip) and try to install it by clicking Packages/install package from local zip file. After install, when I try to load 'dmGWAS' I got the error 'Error: package ‘dmGWAS’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it'. I am using win 7 and R 3.1.0.

I searched similar questions but find no solution.

Comment: [Build](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4739837/271616) from [source](http://bioinfo.mc.vanderbilt.edu/dmGWAS/dmGWAS_2.3.tar.gz).

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich This works on windows or Linux

Comment: Windows (read the first link).

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
> update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE, ask = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

The authors release the newest version dmGWAS_3.0, which is compatible with dmGWAS_2.3. You can use the new version at http://bioinfo.mc.vanderbilt.edu/dmGWAS/