# I am unable to use install.packages with the pkgs parameter to install a package from a local file (Win8.1, R3.10)

Tags: r, install.packages

I am trying to install the `rClr` package. The instructions for this are to copy the package file onto the local computer and use `install.packages(pkgs = "c:/.../rClr_0.5-2.zip")`.  I have a laptop, a server and a desktop. The laptop and the desktop are Windows 8.1, the server Windows 2012. All run R 3.1.0. The desktop installs `rClr` without a problem. The other two return the warning (error) message:

`package ‘c:/.../rClr_0.5-2.zip’ is not available (for R version 3.1.0)`.

I've tried all obvious things. The error is pretty generic, it is given whenever install.packages can't find a file.  The package is compatible with R 3.1.0, as evidenced by the fact it installs on my desktop. I've check for silly mistakes. I've tried moving the file to simpler directory structures (in case `install.packages` had a problem with spaces or special characters), I've given it maximum file permissions, tried playing around a few other things, but nothing makes a difference. I also tried replacing the local reference with a reference to the http link, and tried download another random package from CRAN to see if that would install, and both gave the same error message.  I can't think of anything different in the environment of the laptop and the desktop. install.packages does work when installing the standard packages from CRAN.

Am I missing something obvious?  Is there any known issue with `install.packages` (I thought maybe security but couldn't find anything on internet)?  Are their ways to force an installation?  Can anyone recommend something else to try?

Thanks.

Comment: What if you try `install.packages(..., repos = NULL)`?

Comment: Try starting R in vanilla mode just to be sure there aren't extra elements in Renviron or Rprofile (local or site) causing the issue.

Comment: Actually you beat me to it.  I was just about to come back and comment I'd found a workaround.  The one part of the environment I didn't mention was that I was working through RStudio, not thinking this was relevant.  I thought one other thing I hadn't investigated was whether the package would only install under 32 bits, not 64.  So I called up the 32 and 64 bit versions of R, and tried installing on each, and, hey presto, it installed perfectly.  So it was something to do with the rstudio environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4739837/570918

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install an R package from the source tarball on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739837/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-the-source-tarball-on-windows)