# installing an archived package

Tags: r, package

The package is available on this website.
http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rlandscape/

When I use:

```
install.packages("rlandscape", 
  repos = "http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rlandscape/",         
  type="source")
```

I get the following error:

package 'rlandscape' is not available (for R version 3.1.2)

I have tried older versions too but no luck..

Comment: Try just > install.packages("rlandscape")

Comment: Oh, I see it's in an "Archive" folder, which is why the usual methods don't apply. I don't know what that exactly means...

Comment: Hey Aaron, that return the same error. Based on the website link it is archived not sure if that has an effect or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old (archived) package that is no longer supported. If you really need it, you can install it using `R CMD INSTALL` but you need also to install all its dependencies manually.

Installing your desired package gave me the following:

```
>R CMD INSTALL ~/Downloads/rlandscape_1.0.tar.gz 
* installing to library ‘/Users/mohamedahmed/Rlibs’
ERROR: dependencies ‘spatstat’, ‘deldir’, ‘gWidgets’, ‘gWidgetsRGtk2’ are not available for package ‘rlandscape’
* removing ‘/Users/mohamedahmed/Rlibs/rlandscape’
```

I am not sure all dependencies are still available on CRAN, but it seems to be challenging task.

Comment: I have installed all the dependencies, how do I use the R CMD INSTALL command? thanks

Comment: First, download the package. From Terminal, navigate to the folder where you saved the file and write `R CMD INSTALL rlandscape_1.0.tar.gz `

Comment: I should have mentioned, I'm using Windows.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739837/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-the-source-tarball-on-windows) for instructions.

Answer (score 2):

The `devtools` package has a function that can install archived versions. Try:

```
library("devtools")
install_version("rlandscape",version="1.0",
            repos="http://cran.r-project.org")
```

(You should be able to use `repos=getOption("repos")["CRAN"]` instead, but it looks like your `repos` option is slightly messed up, i.e. the URL is missing the `http://`.)

(The `repos` argument is necessary to work around what I think is a glitch in `install_version`, i.e. [it assumes that `repos` is a length-1 character vector](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/721).)

This should, I think, also automatically install appropriate dependencies -- although it's a bit of a catch-22 if they are in the CRANextra repository for Windows, since that has to be suppressed in order to get `install_version` to work ...

It may also be the case that `install_version` automatically assumes that you want the package and all dependencies installed as source (not binary) installations, in which case you will need to have compilation tools installed.  The `rlandscape` package doesn't actually have any compiled code included, but its dependencies do ...

Comment: When I try this I get an error in the url:  url(sprintf("%s/src/contrib/Meta/archive.rds", repos), "rb"): invalid 'description' argument

Comment: results of `getOption("repos")` and `packageVersion("devtools")` ?

Comment: > getOption("repos")                                                                      CRAN                            CRANextra 
     "http://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk" "http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin"     > packageVersion("devtools")
[1] ‘1.7.0’

Comment: it gives a similar error to before. error in url url(sprintf("%s/src/contrib/Meta/archive.rds", repos), "rb"): unsupported URL scheme

Comment: I've also tried this.

url <- "http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RecordLinkage/rlandscape_1.0.tar.gz"
pkgFile <- "rlandscape_1.0.tar.gz"
download.file(url = url, destfile = pkgFile)



install.packages(c("spatstat", "deldir", "gWidgets","gWidgetsRGtk2"))


install.packages(pkgs=pkgFile, type="source", repos=NULL)
***here an error saying program can't start because libatk-1.0-0.dll is missing from your computer. 

unlink(pkgFile)

Comment: I think your repository default is missing an `http://` at the front.  How did you get it?

Comment: I think the problem you're having with `libatk-1.0.0-dll` is a separate problem with `RGtk`/`gWidgetsRGtk2` -- have you really successfully installed and loaded that package?

Comment: Yes, gWidgetsRGtk2 did install and load. In full:                                                                                           1.  url <- "http://cran.r -project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rlandscape/rlandscape.1.0.tar.gz"                 2.  pkgFile <- "rlandscape_1.0.tar.gz"   3.  download.file(url = url, destfile = pkgFile)    4. install.packages(c("spatstat", "deldir", "gWidgets", "gWidgetsRGtk2"))  5. install.packages(pkgs=pkgFile, type="source", repos=NULL)  At this point I get the libatk-1.0.0-dll error. Indeed last thing is 6. unlink(pkgFile)