# R - could not find function "ltdl.fix"

Tags: r

I'm getting the error:

> could not find function "ltdl.fix"

I have installed the update for R and R Studio (2022.07.01) and ltdl.fix doesnt work as the rgr package isn't available?

Looking for suggestions. Have tried robCompositions and that hasn't worked. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569820/installing-an-archived-package

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.