# How can I install rMaps package in RStudio

Tags: r

I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sSbb3PyaSu8

but when I try to install rMaps package it says

```
install.packages("rMaps")
```

> Warning in install.packages :
>     package ‘rMaps’ is not available (for R version 3.4.0)
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'

Comment: try `install.packages("rMaps", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org/")`

Comment: @Phil same error Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘rMaps’ is not available (for R version 3.4.0)

Comment: That means it hasn't been built for R v3.4 so you'll need to build it yourself. If you're on Windows this post will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739837/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-the-source-tarball-on-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rMaps is not on CRAN. You can install the [dev version](https://github.com/ramnathv/rMaps) from Github.

> ```
> require(devtools)
> install_github('ramnathv/rCharts@dev')
> install_github('ramnathv/rMaps')
> ```